# Задать TextView максимальную ширину, равную половине ширины ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, textview, width, android-constraintlayout

Почему не работает `Guideline` и как правильно реализовать задачу. Нужно задать максимальную ширину `TextView`, равную половине ширины `Layout`. Для этого, я привязал правый край `TextView` к `Guideline`, но при добавлении текста Guideline не работает и текст не переносится на следующую строку. Что не так делаю? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="73dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/show_database_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="TextView" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="end"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="show_database_view" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_record"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:onClick="addRecord"
        android:text="@string/add_record_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/remove_record"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/remove_record"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:onClick="removeRecord"
        android:text="@string/remove_record_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/update_record"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_record" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/update_record"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:onClick="updateRecord"
        android:text="@string/update_record_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/barrier2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/remove_record" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: ширину TextView тоже 0dp поставьте

Answer (score 1):

Тебе необходимо TextView c **android:id="@+id/show_database_view"** поставить атрибут **android:layout_width="0dp"**, что означает что он распределиться до линии **guidline**.

Answer (score 1):

Скопируйте и вставьте разметку ниже для вашего `.xml` файла. `Barrier` вам не нужен, если вам необходимо указать четко половину ширины вашего экрана.

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/show_database_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView TextView " />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_record"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="1"
    android:onClick="addRecord"
    android:text="@string/add_record_text"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/remove_record"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/remove_record"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="1"
    android:onClick="removeRecord"
    android:text="@string/remove_record_text"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/update_record"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_record" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/update_record"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="1"
    android:onClick="updateRecord"
    android:text="@string/update_record_text"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/remove_record" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
```

Answer (score -4):

Попробуй:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Вместо View поставь LinearLayout с вертикальной ориетнацией со своими кнопками.

Comment: Вместо вью советовать поставить лейаут..ну это вообще...

Comment: LinearLayout наследуется от ViewGroup, а последний от View, то есть LinearLayout наследуется от View, и по этому поставить лейаут вместь вью вполне нормальное предложение. Не путайте людей.

Comment: Смешной ты) Разберись сначала перед тем как тыкать наследованием))) Ты понимаешь что View это самый верх? Вьюгруп дает ему много не нужного функционала...утежеляет лейаут..